# SwiftUI horizontal ScrollView wanting to auto centre item

Tags: swift, swiftui

I’m very new to SwiftUI and trying to figure out the best way to handle this.

I have set up a card view and that I have in a horizontal ScrollView. I am trying to get it to snap or align to the next card so it is always central. Think App Store apps or games tab in the header, I want it to behave like this.

I have searched around a lot for this but cant seem to find a solution, at least in SwiftUI. I implemented a similar thing in a UIKit app but I’m looking for a native SwiftUI solution if at all possible. This is what I implemented previously https://github.com/BenEmdon/CenteredCollectionView Though I am trying to seek a lighter and native SwiftUI way of doing this if at all possible as I always felt this was a little heavy for what I need.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, 
           content: {
               HStack {
                   CardView(card: cardDetails)
                   CardView(card: cardDetails)
                   CardView(card: cardDetails)
                   CardView(card: cardDetails)
               }
               .padding(.leading, 10)
})
.frame(height: 250)

struct CardView: View {
    let card: Card

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
                .fill(Color.white)

            VStack {
                Text(card.prompt)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)

                Text(card.answer)
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
            .padding(20)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
        .frame(width: 450, height: 250)
    }
}
```

Any input will be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance for your help.

Here is an image from the App Store, the header section is similar to what I want to achieve, when you scroll through these it scrolls on a per item basis and almost snaps to the next item rather than a free scroll:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an Image that explains what is the goal you want to achieve? I'm thinking about HStack(alignment: .center) in the ScrollView but I don't know if that's what you want

Comment: Hi @MattiaRighetti I have updated an image now, if you look at the top section in the App Store and scroll through these you’ll see how it snaps in to place - this is what I am trying to achieve. This is also a similar example https://github.com/BenEmdon/CenteredCollectionView Which I used in a previous project. I know I can use this but I’m trying to find a lighter and more native SwiftUI way of achieving this if possible

Comment: The only solution that comes to my mind here is to use GeometryReader, because you have to 1. center the card 2. know what card to center at which moment.
In that case you can calculate if the center of the card has passed the snap-point or not and manage the card offset to move in the direction you want, it's not an easy thing to do.

Comment: Ok, thanks - i'll have a play around and update if I find a solution - determined to find a way! :)